# JQuery Access Arrays - Logical mistake possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

so i'm sitting here for hours and now i have to get the Eyes of the Internet to help me out...

So i'm trying to create a Shift Plan. I created a Table (each cell a jQuery Dropdown button with the possible Shifts). on every selection i write the selected Shifts into an array.

The following code snippet is how i do that. I need this in the on click because it will show the total shift time in n extra field.

Later i want save the arrays to a Database an because of that i need to access the calFirstRow array for each employee.

```
var calFirstRow = [,];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){   
    // Do the following stuff for every Employee    
    $.each( jqEmployees, function(index, value){
       var name = value['NAME'];    
       // create array from first row
       $( ".first-row-"+ name +" td button" ).each(function( index ) {
         calFirstRow[name, index] = $( this ).text();
       });
    });//End each Employee  
  });//End Dropdown click
 Here i try to Access the array 
});//End ready
```

the problem is, no matter what i do, in every calFirstRow[name] i get the array from the last Employee.

If i print the Array i get something like [User1: Array, User2: Array] but in each, User1 and 2 is the data of User2 saved...

Im new to jQuery and i maybe miss somethin really fundamental....

Comment: As the question has nothing whatsoever to do with PHP, please don't tag-spam.

Comment: trying to access array outside of the click handler ... will only run once on page load there and will be the empty array

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to treat `calFirstRow` as a two dimensional array, but the way you're accessing it doesn't make any sense. If you pop open your browser's development console and type `[,]`, you'll see this:

```
> [,]
< [undefined × 1]
```

It's got only a single dimension, and JavaScript treats the comma as coming after an element, which you haven't provided, so you have an array containing a single `undefined`.

The next problem happens when you access `calFirstRow[name, index]`. Arrays can only be accessed by a single integer index, and JavaScript doesn't know what to do with `name`, so it ignores it and just uses `index`:

```
> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
> a[1, 2]
< 'c' // The element at index 2
> a[2, 0]
< 'a' // The element at index 0
```

The result is that your loops aren't creating a two dimensional array that matches your table, they're just overwriting `calFirstRow` again and again, which is why your last user's data ends up in it. It *looks* like it's in every row, but really when you access `calFirstRow['User1', 0]` or `calFirstRow['User2', 0]`, you're just accessing `calFirstRow[0]` twice.

Since you're trying to index by the employee's name, and then their column in the table, I think you want to start with an object. `calFirstRow` doesn't seem like the name for what you really want, so let's call it `shiftData`:

```
var shiftData = {}
```

The keys in the object will be your employees' names, and the values will be their array of shifts. For example:

```
> shiftData['Kristjan'] = [1,2,3]
< [1, 2, 3]
> shiftData['Joel'] = [4,5,6]
< [4, 5, 6]
> shiftData
< Object {Kristjan: Array[3], Joel: Array[3]}
    Joel: Array[3]
      0: 4
      1: 5
      2: 6
      length: 3
    Kristjan: Array[3]
      0: 1
      1: 2
      2: 3
      length: 3
```

In your click handler, you can [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) over each employee's row in the table and set their named entry to the result.

```
$.each( jqEmployees, function(employeeIndex, value){
   var name = value['NAME'];
   shiftData[name] = $( ".first-row-"+ name +" td button" ).map(function( columnIndex ) {
     return $( this ).text();
   });
});
```

This will result in a `shiftData` object like I showed in the console above. Each iteration of `map` returns the text of the `td button` in the user's row and column. Those values are aggregated into an array and assigned to `shiftData[name]`.